# VB.NET String.Format FormatException was unhandled

Tags: vb.net

I want to generate a json string but 
What did I do is wrong? Why to this code throws an An unhandled exception

```
Public Function GenerateJsonString(doer As Integer, comment As String, id As Integer) As String
    Dim jsonString As String = String.Format("{done_by:{0}, comment:{1}, request_id:{2}}", doer, comment, id)
    Return jsonString
End Function
```

An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: share your all code

Comment: see my update, I have past all my function code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bracket { is a special character in string.format so you need to use two brackets if you want them in the output like so:

```
Dim jsonString As String = String.Format("{{done_by:{0}, comment:{1}, request_id:{2}}}", 806, "comment", 16233)
```

It outputs

```
{done_by:806, comment:comment, request_id:16233}
```

Which is not valid json since it's missing the "-characters. So to correct that you could do

```
Dim jsonString As String = String.Format("{{""done_by"":{0}, ""comment"":""{1}"", ""request_id"":{2}}}", 806, "comment", 16233)
```

Note that comment is string and also needs the "-characters in value.

Output is correct json:

```
{"done_by":806, "comment":"comment", "request_id":16233}
```

There is also easier and more robust way to do this by serialization:

```
Dim serializer As New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer
Dim jsonString As String = serializer.Serialize(New With {.done_by = 806, .comment = "comment", .request_id = 16233})
```

If you have class library or windows -project it needs System.Web.Extensions reference to your project.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the fact that you have braces in your literal text.  When calling `String.Format`, braces are used to indicate place-holders but you have an opening brace at the beginning of the text and a closing brace at the end.  If you want those literal braces included then you must escape them, i.e.

```
"{{done_by:{0}, comment:{1}, request_id:{2}}}"
```

Comment: This produces invalid json, comment is string